# I run a docker container,but after few minutes , it was killed by himself

Tags: docker

I have run a docker container and using nsenter into it.But after few minutes,this container was killed by himself

```
root@n14:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES
e69069513c8b        sameersbn/mysql          "/start"               25 minutes ago      Up 12 seconds       3306/tcp                                 mysqldb1             
02f3f156b3e7        sameersbn/mysql          "/start"               25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       3306/tcp                                 mysqldb   

root@n14:~# nsenter --target 13823 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid

root@e69069513c8b:/home/git/gitlab# Killed

root@n14:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                    NAMES
e69069513c8b        sameersbn/mysql                   "/start"               55 minutes ago      Exited (0) 28 minutes ago                                               mysqldb1
```

Comment: What does `docker logs` say?

Comment: and `docker events`  https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#events

Comment: @h3nrik     
    
 150729 05:50:20 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
 150729 05:52:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended